# Difference between {... | ...} and {... : ...}

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Is there a difference between the following two set related notations:

$$\{~\dots~:~\dots~\}~\text{vs.}~\{~\dots~|~\dots~\}?$$

I take it they both mean "such that" but I was wondering why some authors prefer one to the other, maybe there is a historical background to it?

Comment: I usually prefer the latter, but in some texts use the former (esp. when the conditions are full of $|x|$ and $y\mid z$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In a paper I was making up for a conference proceeding volume, the separator was $|$, $:$ or $;$, with no apparent reason, except for the fact that the paper had three authors.

Comment: What is the difference between $]a,b[$ and $(a,b)$ and why do some authors prefer one to the other?

Comment: Note that "such that" is not what the symbol _means_, but merely how the notation is _pronounced_. The _meaning_ of the symbol $\{x\mid \phi(x)\}$ is the unique set $y$ with the property $\forall x(x\in y\leftrightarrow \phi(x))$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Same here, I guess. I was raised with the former, but mostly use the latter (esp. because you need \left and \right to get good  spacing with the former), but am unhappy with it if I need ordered pairs in the same text ... :)

Comment: @Hagen: Easy fix, $\langle a,b\rangle$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I knew you'd say that, but I often use that for dot product :)

Comment: @Hagen: What's wrong with $a\cdot b$, then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's exactly the same. But if you need a "such that " twice, it's better to use $\mid$ and then $:$. For example,
$$\{y\mid \exists x\in \mathbb R: y=f(x)\}$$

Comment: why is $| \ldots :$ better than $:\ldots |$?

Comment: Well, graphically it looks better :-)

Answer (score 5):

They are the same, but there are occasion where one would be less practical to use. For example the $|$ sign has [uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar#Mathematics) that makes $|$ non-practical for set building. For example $\{P|ab: P\in X\}$ (ie the set of distances to the line $ab$ for points in $X$) and $\{f|_A: f\in X\}$ (ie the set of restrictions to $A$ for functions in $X$) would be less obvious if you used $|$ sign instead of $:$ sign. There are other uses for the $:$ sign to (fx mappings which would lead to constructs like $\{f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb Z|\, f(-x)=f(x)\}$) so if there's risk of running into these cases the author should select the notation that results in the least confusing set-building notation.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between both notation. One author may prefer the first one, the other the second one. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation for more details.